# Android activity memory leak when using foreground service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks, android-service

I have an app which uses an activity to launch a foreground service, that's intended to be used without the activity, and persists after navigating away from the application. The service can also be launched on boot.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of memory the service uses, and noticed that when the service is launched from the activity, the used memory is anywhere from 30mb - 80mb, and in the memory profiler in Android Studio, its shown that there's a memory leak and that the main activity of the app (that launched the service) is still referenced even though it says it's destroyed. If the service is launched from boot, using a broadcast reciever, the activity isn't referenced, and the used memory is around 10mb.

I've tried using LeakCanary but it didn't find any leaks, while the memory profile explicitly gives a leak warning for the activity. I haven't been able to find the reference that's making it be retained in memory.

I tried starting the service with:

```
serviceintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);    
getApplicationContext().startService(serviceintent);
```

But the results are the same.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538533/releasing-memory-from-activity-of-foreground-service) guy had the same question and resolved it with using seperate processes:

And I've read others who said its normal android behavior and that the activity is attached to the process, but Android Studio says it's a leak? Why is that? Even after messing around with my phone in order to get it to free up memory, it got down to 26mb, but the activity is still referenced, and 6,7mb goes to graphics always, while its 0mb, when launched from boot.

Is it possible to fix this without using multiple processes, just like when started from boot? How can I know where the Activity gets referenced?

[Screenshot of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq3Ll.png)

Comment: Have you walked up the reference chain and found where the root reference is?

Comment: @GabeSechan What does that mean exactly? I checked in some of the places listed in the references part of the window that didn't seem familiar, but there's so many references, I could probably be searching for a very long time since I don't know where to look

Comment: The heap trace includes all places that reference an object.  The one with the lowest depth is generally what keeps it in memory (although not always).  Trace that back and you can find out what's keeping it in memory.  That's how you solve memory leaks.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I was aware that those are all the references to the object, btw I think theres no getting around this without using two seperate processes based on some research, but thanks for the tip, maybe I find some answer in that lowest one

Comment: It is likely that your `MainActivity` has created a callback or some asynchronous process that is holding a reference to the `MainActivity`. Does `MainActivity` have any `static` variables?

Comment: @DavidWasser nope, theres a static function, but anyway, I began transitioning the app to have the service run on a separate process and so far it seems to be working great with much less ram consumed